# Binarize an image and extract a text where the background is black and the text to be extract is red?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying extract text from a screenshot using `cv2` and `pytesseract` in memory.

When the text is white over a black background it works, but when the text is red the return is always empty.

```
import sys
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pytesseract import pytesseract

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\site-packages\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

def Extract(tupleCoordenates):

pic = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=tupleCoordenates)
img = np.array(pic)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
limiar, imgThreash = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgThreash)
return text
```

PS: this code below works when i save the pic on disk and get it from cv2.imread("myimage.jpeg", 0)

```
myImg = cv2.imread("myimage.jpeg", 0)    
limiar, imgThreash = cv2.threshold(myImg, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite(args[2], imgThreash)
```

I believe that the problem is the parse from pic -> img -> gray scale

Comment: Have you tried to convert the image to grayscale explicitly when using ImageGrab.grab()?

Comment: I'm trying convert from a numpy array.

Comment: What does `imgThreash` look like when you start with an image with red text? Is the text visible? Probably not, I suspect your threshold is too high. If your text is **only** ever red or white, you could try using only the red channel instead of converting to grayscale. It's hard to tell without sample images.

Comment: Try `pic = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=tupleCoordenates).convert('L')` then you don't have to worry about OpenCV's BGR ordering being different from PIL. Then convert that to a Numpy array.

Comment: beaker, imgThreash  is the result from opencv where it try gives the image in a .tiff file black and withe just.

Comment: Mark, I did this but does not worked

Comment: @wmendes I understand what `imgThreash` is. I asked if you had tried to view it to see if your results were what you expected. Please note that if you do not add the @ in front of the name of the person you're replying to, they will not be notified that you've responded.

Comment: @beaker, sorry about that! So, I take a look and i saw that cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) is returning everything white therefore removing the text in red.

Comment: Then you should probably debug that.

Comment: @beaker, I think the problem is a litle more complicated. How a mentioned, I have a white text over a backgroud(black + gray) and a red text over the same background. I did observe that limiarization result  recording in file pytesseract extracts the text that was white over black and now is black over white but the text that was red over black and now is black over white it doesn't. these same file images the tesseract in .Net C# extract both! I believe that exists something in pytesseract  missing in version or my limitation on the way the opencv limiarization.

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/image-grayscale-tesseract-ocr/14142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem.

Follows the code:

```
def ThresholdFromScreenShot(tupleCoordenates):

pixels = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=tupleCoordenates))

gray_f = np.array(Image.fromarray(pixels).convert('L'))

limiar, imgThreash = cv2.threshold(gray_f, 127, 255, 
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

gray_s = np.array(Image.fromarray(imgThreash).convert('L'))
            
blur = cv2.blur(gray_s,(3,3))

limiar,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,240,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
return thresh
```